# Securing remote access to my amazon ec2 machines

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp

I am looking for an automated solution or script that can set the security group of my Amazon EC2 machines, so that only my current IP address can be the source of an RDP connection. I am looking for an automated solution, that works the following>

1. I run my script or app that would get my IP address and update the security group that only my IP can be the source of an RDP connection
2. Connect to my Amazon EC2 machine using EC2
3. Do the work

Is there any application or script that I can use for this? Is this a good idea at all to secure my machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is called "boto", it's a python interface to the Amazon APIs, including [security group management](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/ec2_tut.html#security-groups).  This link takes you to examples of Python code that interacts with the security groups.

Comment: thanks for the anser. The link you have just posted will help me getting started. I accept your answer :)

Comment: What's the advantage of boto over the EC2 API tools? http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2012-06-15/CommandLineReference/OperationList-cmd.html